# android/sqlite: Cannot create Database in altered path

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a database file in other location, but the app always failed to do so.

```
        try {
        File sdcardfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(sdcardfile.getPath()+ "/test.db", null);
        System.out.println("Its open? "  + db.isOpen());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText("error is "+e.toString());// tv is a text view
    }
```

I can create any database, as long as it doesn't use altered path.
It work fine if I use "test.db", but not if I use   "//test.db".

This is the logcat text:

```
01-21 20:14:19.470: I/Database(3678): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

The Error it throws me is : `SQLite exception: unable to open database file.`
I use BlueStack as my emulator.

Thank you all for reading.

Edited: my apps fails because it lacks WRITE PERMISSION... insert it and everything's ok.

Comment: Give logcat log , please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guessing (information missing in your question), but did you request permission to access the SD card in your app's manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is save database in folder : /data/data/you.package.name/database , using SQLiteDatabaseOpenHelper. Read about this [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). I hope I helped

**EDIT :**

This is simple code :

```
package com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad;

import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.HASH;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.INT1;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.INT2;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.INT3;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.KIEDY;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.KTO;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.KTORY;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.LOGIN;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.NAZWA_TABELI1;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.NAZWA_TABELI2;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.NAZWA_TABELI3;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.TRESC;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.TYTUL;
import static com.radzik.mypersolnalnotepad.Stale.WANN;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Bazodanowiec extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String NAZWA_BAZY = "database.db";
    public static final int WERSJA_BAZY = 1;

    public Bazodanowiec(Context kon)
    {
        super(kon, NAZWA_BAZY, null, WERSJA_BAZY );
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bd)
    {
        bd.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI1 + " (" + INT1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + LOGIN + " VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, " + HASH + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL);");
        bd.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI2 + " (" + INT2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TYTUL + " VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, " + TRESC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KIEDY + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " + KTO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(kto) REFERENCES konta(id1));");
        bd.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI1 + " (" + INT3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KTORY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + WANN + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FOREIGN KEY(ktory) REFERENCES konta(id1));");
    }


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI1 + ";");
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI2 + ";");
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI3 + ";");
      onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

"Stale" is interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this method after

Answer (score 0):

Did you get WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for your app?
I had good results with this in my DatabaseHelper:

```
    public DatabaseHelper(final Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + FILE_DIR
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this way :

> ```
> private static String DB_PATH;
> public DataBaseHelper(Context p_context)
> {
> try
> {
>     m_context = p_context;
>     if (DB_PATH == null)
>     {
>         DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ p_context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +File.separatorChar+ "databases" + File.separatorChar + "/test.db";
>         }
>         openOrCreateDatabase();
>         m_dbhelper = new DBHelper(this.m_context, DB_PATH, null, DBConstant.DATABASE_VERSION);
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```